# Error trying to set text field text to string

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, nsstring, uitextfield

I am trying to set my text field's text equal to a saved string. I have it global because I need to access it at another point. I get this error: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_tailNum", referenced from:
      -[rvc newPlaneClicked:] in rvc.o
  "_MM", referenced from:
      -[rvc newPlaneClicked:] in rvc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

What is causing this/how is it fixed?

```
extern NSString *tailNum;
extern NSString *MM;

- (void)newPlaneClicked:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *newPlaneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlightLog Pro" message:@"Enter tail number and make/model:"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];

    newPlaneAlert.delegate = self;
    [newPlaneAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

    UITextField *enterNewPlaneTail = [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *enterNewPlaneMM = [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1];

    [enterNewPlaneTail setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a make/model."];
    [enterNewPlaneMM setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a plane tail number."];

    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocorrectionType = YES;

    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1].autocorrectionType = YES;
    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1].secureTextEntry = NO;

    [newPlaneAlert show];

    enterNewPlaneTail.text = tailNum;
    enterNewPlaneMM.text = MM;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put these declarations

```
extern NSString *tailNum;
extern NSString *MM;
```

into your `.h` file and in the global scope of your `.m` file assign some values to them:

```
NSString *tailNum = @"tailNum";
NSString *MM      = @"MM";
```

also read more about extern variables. you can start from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable). [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/) is one more explanation